# Use Django as an API backend for an iOS app?

Tags: python, django, security

I've got an iOS app that I need to write an API for, and I'd like to use Django as a backend. However, I keep running into various security features that I would rather not disable or ignore, such as anti-CSRF measures when accepting POST requests.

Is there any literature about using Django as a backend for an API? What about API security in general? Is this even a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home). It's a decent framework for django for creating RESTful APIs.